How can I add menu button in telegram bot like the follow picture？
(https://i.sstatic.net/JkzPIO2C.png)
[When the redlined button is highlighted, the button below the input box appears]
I don't know what it's called, so I don't know what to search for
I expect to know how it's set up or what it's called in the telegram Api doc, I didn't find a corresponding setting on the relevant documentation, so maybe I'm missing it

I think you are looking for ReplyKeyboardMarkup

please post your attempt, where you failed and how we can help you. don't just expect someone will jump in and write your code. this is not a freelance hire platform.

Those buttons are called ReplyKeyboardMarkup.
Here's how you can send a Keyboard to your bot's user:
    const chatId = 1234;
    const message = "Hello World";
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, message, {
        reply_markup: {
            keyboard: [
                // Row 1
                [
                    { text: " Balance" },
                    { text: "⚙️ Settings" },
                ],
                // Row two
                [
                    { text: "Button on the Second Row" }
                ]
            ]
        }
    });

These buttons support a variety of functions like -

It can be used to ask for user's location
It can be used to ask user's phone number

And much more. Read all about it on the official docs.
Hope this helps :)
